# Cant find and replace all the occurances of the vector

Tags: c++

- I am supposed to be able to decode a secret message using vectors.
- I have all of the vectors written out and can find the first instance that comes up.
- I also can only find one vector at a time.
- I am supposed to be able to decode messages like "**,$]:**" (which is supposed to spell "**tops**").
- I am not including the whole list of vectors because that would be to long:

  ```
  ...
  sym.at(i)="$"; letr.at(i) = "o"; ++i;
  sym.at(i)="]"; letr.at(i) = "p"; ++i;
  sym.at(i)="}"; letr.at(i) = "q"; ++i;
  sym.at(i)=";"; letr.at(i) = "r"; ++i;
  sym.at(i)=":"; letr.at(i) = "s"; ++i;
  sym.at(i)=","; letr.at(i) = "t"; ++i;
  sym.at(i)="%"; letr.at(i) = "u"; ++i;
  sym.at(i)="<"; letr.at(i) = "v"; ++i;
  sym.at(i)="."; letr.at(i) = "w"; ++i;
  sym.at(i)=">"; letr.at(i) = "x"; ++i;
  sym.at(i)="/"; letr.at(i) = "y"; ++i;
  sym.at(i)="?"; letr.at(i) = "z"; ++i;

  cout << "\nEnter decrypted message: "; //asking dycypted message
  cin >> message;

  found = false;
  for (i = 0; i < numCar; ++i) { // find letter index
      if (sym.at(i) == message) {
          found = true;
          cout << "decrypted message is: ";
          cout << letr.at(i) << endl;
      }
  }
  ...
  ```

Comment: Did you check [<algorithm>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/) ?

Comment: Use an `unordered_map` for it. With key the decrypted `char` and value the `char` that maps to.

Comment: Hint: `sym.at(i) == message` will never be `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Cant find and replace all the occurances of the vector:

- Obviously you can't, supposed that `message == ",$]:"` the conditional in your `for` loop `sym.at(i) == message` will never become `true`. Consequently, the code in your `if` clause will never be evaluated.

---

### How you could easily do it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::string sym("$]};:,%<.>/?");
  std::string let("opqrstuvwxyz");

  std::string inpt;
  while (std::getline(std::cin, inpt)) {
    for (std::size_t i(0), ie(inpt.size()); i < ie; ++i) {
      std::size_t idx = std::distance(sym.begin(), std::find(sym.begin(), sym.end(), inpt[i]));
      if (idx < sym.size()) std::cout << let[idx];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bacdbd5483ce5856)